# How do I register a custom classloader with Hibernate's ClassLoaderService?

Tags: hibernate, groovy, classloader

### Background

I have a set of Groovy files which I parse as classes using Groovy's classloader:

```
    GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader();
    while (groovyIter.hasNext()) {
      File groovyFile = (File) groovyIter.next();
      try {
        Class clazz = gcl.parseClass(groovyFile);
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
        log.error("Unable to read file " + groovyFile + " to parse class ", ioe);
      }
    }
```

Once the GroovyClassLoader is complete I parse XML files using XStream to deserialize the XML as different instances of Groovy objects. I'm starting with one type for now: invoice. So that XStream can see the groovy classes, I set the classloader to be the instance of the GroovyClassLoader.

```
  XStream xstream = new XStream();
  xstream.setClassLoader(gcl); 

  // Read the file and get objects
  Object deserialized = xstream.fromXML(file);
```

Once I have the de-serialized object I want to store it in a database using Hibernate. In my hibernate.config.xml I have a mapping entry

<mapping class="invoice"/>

Which maps to my annotated groovy class

```
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import groovy.transform.ToString
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import javax.persistence.Table
import javax.persistence.Column

@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table(name="invoice")
class invoice {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  Long id

  String invoicedate
  String invoicenumber

  String ponumber
  String salesrep
  String servicedate
  String terms
  String duedate

  String notes
  String subtotal
  String discountpercent
  String discountamount
  String total
  String paid
  String totaldue

}
```

### The problem:

When I try to open a session I get class not found.

```
    Configuration hibernateConfig = new Configuration();

    Properties hibernateConfigProps = hibernateConfig.getProperties();
    hibernateConfigProps.put("hibernate.classLoader.application", gcl);
    hibernateConfig.setProperties(hibernateConfigProps);

    SessionFactory sf = hibernateConfig.configure(new File("hibernate.config.xml")).buildSessionFactory();        
    Session sess = sf.openSession();
```

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class [ invoice] declared in Hibernate configuration  entry.

I tried setting hibernate.classLoader.application property to the GroovyClassLoader instance and then setting the property in the configuration, but no luck.

My searches have turned up that I might need to use org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService but I'm not sure how to do this with Hibernate.

See below for stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:342)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:168)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class [ invoice] declared in Hibernate configuration <mapping/> entry
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2139)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2087)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2067)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2020)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1993)
    at com.referencelogic.xmlormupload.main.XmlormuploadMain.run(XmlormuploadMain.java:101)
    at     com.referencelogic.xmlormupload.main.XmlormuploadMain.main(XmlormuploadMain.java:54)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: invoice
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.JarClassLoader.findClass(JarClassLoader.java:713)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.JarClassLoader.loadClass(JarClassLoader.java:630)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2136)
    ... 12 more
```

Tried as suggested setting the thread's context class loader, but Hibernate is ignoring it.

```
    ClassLoader oldcl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();        
    System.out.println("Old classloader is " + oldcl);
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(gcl);
    ClassLoader newcl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    System.out.println("New classloader is " + newcl);

    Configuration hibernateConfig = new Configuration();

    System.out.println("Hibernate config class loader is: " + hibernateConfig.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

results in

```
Old classloader is com.simontuffs.onejar.JarClassLoader@5c58d6b0
New classloader is groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader@3ed4b480
Hibernate config class loader is: com.simontuffs.onejar.JarClassLoader@5c58d6b0
```

Followed by the previously mentioned stack trace.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: I'm using Hibernate version 4.1.7

Comment: What you have should do the trick from a Java perspective; I am unsure about any specifics of Groovy classloading that might be in play here (if any).  Can you show the stack trace?  Btw, that setting is in fact one targetting the `ClassLoaderService`

Comment: I'm also using One-Jar which implements a JarClassLoader... It was fine with XStream, but if my code for setting the hibernate classloader is fine it may be overriding Hibernate's custom class loader setting somehow.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Been working on master and 5.0 code too much.  For 4.0/4.1 the ClassLoaderService is not used to load mapping stuff.  You can set the TCCL while building the Configuration, which will get you what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your time on this. Tried setting the thread's class loader, but Hibernate is ignoring it. Updated post.

Comment: You'll have to debug into org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper#classForName and see why it misses looking up via TCCL.

Comment: So debugged and it's one-jar's fault that the thread's classloader isn't being seen as updated by Hibernate. As part of its classloader implementation it resets the current thread's classloader to the one-jar jarclassloader whenever loadClass is called. Will try to patch one-jar so it works setting the context classloader in exceptional situations. Thanks again for your time.